# How can I replace certain strings in variable table all at once?

Tags: 6

I would like to replace all the 'aaaa' strings with 'bbbbbb' in value column of variable table.

I was initially trying to do that with just a simple query like this.

```
UPDATE variable SET `value` = replace(`value`,'aaaa','bbbbbb')
```

But this didn't work properly and I was taught that also the number between `s: and :"`  in value column has to be changed accordingly.

So variable_set seems to be the way to go but I'm not able to get it work.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/variable_set/6

How can I do this?

Comment: It is not really a Drupal question, not even a PHP one (you know all there is to know from PHP side), just MySQL. You need to [`LOCATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) first `:` after 2nd byte, take a [`SUBSTRING`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substr) after it, `REPLACE` what you need, get [`LENGTH`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_length) of result, and [`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) new value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable holds serialized data, so you can't modify what you want with a simple query. You have you to get every variable value  with variable_get, process the value making the needed replacement and the save the variable using varaable_set.

You can get all vlaues with this snippet:

```
$variables = db_query('SELECT name FROM {variable}'); 

foreach ($variables as $variable_name) {
  $variable_value = variable_get($variable_name, NULL);
  $fixed_variable_value = your_replace_function($variable_value);
  variable_set($variable_name, $fixed_variable_value);
}
```

You will need the your_replace_function(). This function must deal with all possible values because $variable_value can be a number, a string, an array, object or any other PHP type. In case of arrays and object the function must process its nested components.

Comment: Good way. But, you know... maybe not "simple", but one indeed can build a query for this task. See my comment under OP's question. In fact I did it, once. It can work. You **can** do it purely in SQL.

Comment: It will work also with a serialized multilevel array? I mean, this will need some kind of recursion over the string to modify, I guess. But sure it will definitely very interesting to write a MySQL expression that replaces parts of a PHP serialized value.

Comment: @tunic _"But sure it will definitely very interesting to write a MySQL expression that replaces parts of a PHP serialized value"_ You need to replace "interesting" with "nasty, and indicative that you're doing something terribly wrong" ;)

Comment: :D Well, I'm not a MySQL expert, but if such expression is possible and works it may be useful in some situations... if you don't need more hours to develop it than doing it by hand or with PHP, of course.

Comment: @Clive I did it, once, exactly because it was interesting exercise. Actually using it, especially in production environment, would be nasty. But to test if it's possible? Why not? ;)